# What is the etymology of "strength" in the sense of "a tensorial strength"?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, math-history

Tensorial strength, and the notion of a functor having "a strength," is discussed on the nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensorial+strength

What was the original reason for this name? Is it due to CS Peirce, or does it come from one of the application domains of category theory?

Comment: It looks like it was introduced without justification in Kock's [Monads on symmetric monoidal closed categories](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01220868) (he cites Eilenberg–Kelly's [Closed categories](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-99902-4_22) for terminology, but "strong" and "strength" don't appear there).

Comment: I always assumed it was related to "strong monoidal functor". But maybe at the time people still called strong monoidal functors "weak monoidal functors"?

Answer (score 4):

I asked Anders Kock, and this is his answer:

> In the article of mine quoted (Monads on Symm. Monoidal Closed
> Categories, 1970, page 1), the word strength for a functor is used as
> synonymous with enriched, i.e. as a $V$-functor., and was in fact
> denoted by "st". I believe it may have been folklore usage at that
> time. In loc.cit., I construct out of a strong $T: V \to V$ a tensorial
> strength t', and prove in the follow-up paper 1972 that t' and st
> correspond to each other (Strong Functors and Monoidal Monads, 1972,
> Proposition 1.1). Over time, "strength" has mainly come to mean
> tensorial strength.

Comment: I'm holding off on accepting this as the answer, because although it describes (in a very "structural" way) *how* Kock and others used the word, it doesn't describe *why* he chose it. As varkor commented, he seemingly introduced it without justification. I'm interested in the motivation behind the term, as I hope my question made clear.

Comment: I have a theory, which may be wrong. Internal hom is also called the exponential object, so it's one object to the _power_ of enother. So strength might be related to preserving power, since a strong (in the sense of "enriched") functor maps internal homs.